# Why does this print 5 7 8 11 19?

Tags: java

```
public static void mystery(int[] data)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < data.length - 1; k++)
        data[k+1] = data[k] + data[k+1]; 

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] values = {5,2,1,3,8};
    mystery(values);
    for(int v : values)
        System.out.println(v + " ");


}
```

This confuses me; isnt mystery void? it shouldnt be updating any values 
5 
7 
8 
11 
19

Comment: Void is the return type which returns nothing.data[k+1] = data[k] + data[k+1]; is where it increments.

Comment: Java is pass by reference for arrays, the array instance is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Run it in debugger mode so that you should see in yourself why it's printing like that.
https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-debug-launch.htm

Answer (score 0):

To explain what is happening, understanding Java's parameter passing is important; especially [whether it's “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

Starting off by defining the terms "**pass-by-value**" semantics and "**pass-by-reference**" is prudent:

- **Pass-by-value**: The actual parameter (or argument expression) is fully evaluated and the resulting value is copied into a location being used to hold the formal parameter's value during method/function execution. That location is typically a chunk of memory on the runtime stack for the application (which is how Java handles it), but other languages could choose parameter storage differently.
- **Pass-by-reference**: The formal parameter merely acts as an alias for the actual parameter. Anytime the method/function uses the formal parameter (for reading or writing), it is actually using the actual parameter.

Java is strictly pass-by-value, exactly like in C. See the following citations from the Java Language Specification (JLS):

> When the method or constructor is invoked (§15.12), the values of the
>   actual argument expressions initialize newly created parameter
>   variables, each of the declared type, before execution of the body of
>   the method or constructor. The Identifier that appears in the
>   FormalParameter may be used as a simple name in the body of the method
>   or constructor to refer to the formal parameter.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1

> The argument expressions (possibly rewritten as described above) are
>   now evaluated to yield argument values. Each argument value
>   corresponds to exactly one of the method's n formal parameters.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.2

Like all Java objects, arrays are passed by value. However, the value is the reference to the array. So, when you assign something to a cell of the array in the called method, you will be assigning to the same array object that the caller sees.

In the code snippet you shared:

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] values = {5,2,1,3,8};

    mystery(values); // this call will pass the reference by value

    for(int v : values)
        System.out.println(v + " ");


}
```

`mystery(values)` will pass a reference to the array `values` by value and the operations of the receiver `mystery(int[] data)` will modify the array `values` that is pointed to by that reference.

`void` is a return type which implies, as Java is a typed language, the type of the result expected from `mystery(int[] data)`.

You can read some more about it [here](http://www.javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm)